# how to prevent sticky footer from overlapping above content when zooming in

Tags: css, xhtml, overlap, sticky-footer

I have this webpage with a sticky footer, and when zooming in too much, the footer and its content overlaps the above content.  How do i prevent that? here is the link:

http://www.hitone101.com/

Comment: That site doesn't even seem to exist any more. Can you paste whatever the code used to be into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `#footer` a style of `overflow: hidden;`.

Don't use a fixed width for `#footercontent`!

Especially not an outrageously high value of `1920px`!

Remember that your users will be visiting on all kinds of devices, and may not have their browser window(s) maximized.

When users see the [horizontal-scrollbar-of-DOOM™](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20050711.html) they will flee the site, post haste.

---

#### Update for newer page:

It seemed to be a combination of conflicting width and margin settings; I ended up starting with a clean reset.

Try:
**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <title> Hightone - Landing Page </title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
    <meta name="title" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noble" rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="header">&nbsp;</header><!-- #header-->
    <div id="content">
        <div id="logoholderDiv">
            <img src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div id="videoDiv">
            <!--<img id = "xboxImg" src = "images/xbox.png" />-->
            <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ee0bWAwgCRE" allowfullscreen="">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #content-->
</div><!-- #wrapper -->
<footer id="footer">
    <div id="footercontent">
        <a href="http://www.hitone101.com/index.html">ENTER SITE</a>
    </div>
</footer><!-- #footer -->
</body></html>
```

**CSS:**

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
header, nav, section, article, aside, footer {
    display: block;
}
body {
  /*  font: 12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; */
    height: 100%;
}
a {
    color: blue;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 18px
}
img {
    border: none;
}
input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#wrapper {
    width:              auto;
    min-width:          1000px;
    min-height:         100%;
    height:             auto !important;
    height:             100%;
    background:         url( "images/landing_page_bg.png" );
    border:             1px solid blue;
}


/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
    height:             1px;
}

/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#content {
    padding:            0 0 343px;
}

/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#footer {
    margin:             -343px auto 0;
    min-width:          1000px;
    height:             343px;
    background:         url( "images/landing_page_footer.png" )no-repeat;
    background-size:    100%;
    background-color:   black;
}

.selfclear:             after {
    content:            ".";
    float:              left;
    display:            block;
    height:             0;
    clear:              both;
    visibility:         hidden;
}
#logoholderDiv {
    width:              150px;
    height:             142px;
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
}
#videoDiv {
    width:              650px;
    height:             551px;
    background:         url( "images/videobg.png" ) no-repeat;
    margin-top:         30px;
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
}
#videoDiv > iframe {
    width:              650px;
    height:             551px;
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
    border:             1px solid red;
}
#footercontent {
    height:             89%;
    background:         url( "images/footer_logo.png" ) 45.9% no-repeat;
    border:             1px solid brown;
    padding-top:        20px;
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
    overflow:           hidden;
}
#footercontent > a {
    padding:            0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align:         center;
    text-decoration:    none;
    color:              white;
    display:            block;
    font-size:          50px;
    width:              100%;
    margin:             10px auto 0px auto;
    border:             1px solid;
}
```

Comment: k i just uploaded the new page

Comment: why would you include a header of 1px height?  Thanks, your code works, but im trying to learn this sticky footer thing 100% lol...

Comment: ohhh i get it now, the three key components that make the footer stay at the bottom and not overlap in zoom in/out is bottom-padding for content section, negative bottom margin for wrapper, and footer with negative top margin...wow after soo much frustration and effort i finally get it lol...thanks again.  One more thing tho, why can't i include the bottom-padding on the wrapper instead of the content section?

Comment: Basically what I did was revert to a tested, standard variation of that layout.  A lot of the why's and wherefores come from years of bitter experience by a lot of people -- I don't know them all.  I would recommend not changing that basic scheme.  Even if you think you haven't busted it on your browser, chances are that for some other browser ¤cough¤ IE ¤cough¤, you did.  I left the header in, in case some future pages want/need it (odds are strong, they will).

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, the footer should be `position:fixed` with `bottom:0px`.  To prevent it from overlapping too much on resize, You might want to set it to a % height.